# socat with a virtual tty link and fork removes my pty link

Tags: sockets, tcp, serial-port, listener, socat

I require to be able to multiplex tcp connections to a single virtual tty for testing software that communicates over a serial port. I have been using the following command to create a server that listens on a tcp port, and then forwards data to the PTY.

```
socat -d -d PTY,link=/dev/ttyV1,waitslave,echo=0,raw TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork
```

My problem is when a tcp client on port 11313 disconnects, socat removes my link to /dev/ttyV1, thus killing the session to everyone else who is connected.

Is there a way to retain this link? Or perhaps create a pseudo tty outside of socat so that I don't have to worry about maintaining it? I've tried /dev/tty1 and /dev/ttyS1 and I've not had any luck. My command for these was:

```
socat -d -d file:/dev/tty1,nonblock,echo=0,raw TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork
```

My requirement: Be able to connect a piece of software to a serial tty on one end, and then connect a number of tcp clients on the other. Tcp clients messaging is properly serialized and multiplexed so that messages don't arrive on top of each other.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have found a solution for myself. You have to create a virtual null modem pair first, then open one end of the virtual null modem pair and link it with the TCP listener. `socat -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVA00 PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVB00`. Then `socat -d -d open:/dev/ttyVA00,nonblock,echo=0,raw TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork` I can connect as many clients as I want, and everything seems to be working.

Comment: If that works, can you put it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I seem to have found a solution for myself. You have to create a virtual null modem pair first, then open one end of the virtual null modem pair and link it with the TCP listener.

```
socat -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVA00 PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVB00
```

Then

```
socat -d -d open:/dev/ttyVA00,nonblock,echo=0,raw TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork
```

I can connect as many clients as I want, and everything seems to be working.

Comment: +1 this helped me a lot. However why do you create two virtual serial ports?

Comment: When using fork, the pty link is always going to get disconnected and removed when the client disconnects. As a result, in the example above, when someone connects to /dev/ttyVB00, and then disconnects, /dev/ttyVB00 will be removed by SOCAT. As a result, when someone else tries to connect, there will be no PTY to connect to. The first pair is to ensure there is always a null pair available, the second pair is to connect one of the pairs with the fork call on a listening tcp port.

Comment: This way, on disconnect the original null pair on ttyVA00 and ttyVB00 always remains open for future connections. Hopefully this is an okay explanation! It's clear in my mind, but does not always come out clear when I'm trying to write it out :)

Comment: So I would always write to /dev/ttyVB00 because ttyVA00 is just the connector?

Comment: You bet, that is correct. In the example above, port 11313 will connect to /dev/ttyVB00.

Answer (score 5):

why not just use "unlink-close=0"?

e.g.

```
socat -d -d PTY,link=/dev/ttyV1,waitslave,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork
```

Comment: @srclosson I tried this command, however it does not create a TCP server. Because of wait-slave?